# Why does Olivia Rodrigo say "We broke up a month ago" in her song 'Happier'?

Tags: lyrics

*Happier* was released on May 21, 2021.

Fans are speculating that the *Sour* album is about Joshua Bassett (Olivia's ex-boyfriend) and Sabrina Carpenter (Joshua's current girlfriend); which is likely to be true.

Olivia's first song was *driver's license* which was released on January 8, 2021 (also in *Sour*).

If the songs are about one thing, how did she say "We broke up a month ago" in *Happier* while she has sung about her ex in January too?

Comment: Well, songs are not usually released in days. i.e. the fact that it was released in May, doesn't mean it was written in that month or even that year as well...

Comment: @Tomerikoo You could probably turn that comment into an answer.

Comment: @PiedPiper Well I couldn't find any reference for the *writing* date of the song or any other example for a song being released later than written so this is more of a personal feeling/guess so feels weird to be an actual answer. If I can find something to base it on, I will turn it to an answer

Comment: @Tomerikoo songs are necessarily released after they are written unless the song is composed extemporaneously during a live broadcast, for the simple reason that a song's composition must take place before or during the recording session, and the recording session must take place before the release.  The time between composition and release could be fairly short, but it would more typically be measured in weeks or even months.

Answer (score 2):

Olivia had been writing songs for her album *Sour* months prior to its release. She took to Instagram to post covers of her songs in their beginning stages, many of which have since been deleted. However, fans have uploaded those covers to YouTube, including this video of *[Happier](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S8Nas_9LE44)*. This video was originally uploaded to her [Instagram](https://www.instagram.com/oliviarodrigo/?hl=en) on January 13th, 2020. Although we don't hear the lyric "We broke up a month ago" in this particular video, we can assume it was written when it actually had been month following her breakup with Joshua.
There are countless videos and articles explaining the [timeline](https://www.bustle.com/entertainment/olivia-rodrigo-joshua-bassett-relationship-timeline) of the love triangle between Olivia, Joshua, and Sabrina, which might give more insight into the story behind the song.

Answer (score 1):

Without wishing to detract from Payton Pingree's [detailed answer](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/a/12267/1642), I would add that poetry generally may evoke a particular past moment in time.  [William Wordsworth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Wordsworth) described poetry thus:

> the spontaneous overflow of powerful feelings: it takes its origin from emotion recollected in tranquility

In that model, this poem may be seen as a depiction of the emotion experienced by the author roughly one month after the breakup.  The author recollected that emotion on writing the poem and invites us to experience it as well by hearing the poem (and the music that accompanies it).  We may consider what it is like to be one month past a breakup at any time, regardless of when the words may actually have been written, much less of when the song may have been written, recorded, or performed.

Comment: Can we consider _song lyrics_ poems?

Comment: @aminabzz why wouldn't you?

Comment: As far as I know, a poem is **literary**, not an everyday life thing like the words of a popular song. If a songwriter can be called a poet, then why don't we see the word poet in the songs personnel list?

Comment: @aminabzz as far as I understand it, song lyrics _are_ literary; the Swedish Academy [obviously agrees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2016_Nobel_Prize_in_Literature), at least.  The controversy around the award to Dylan did not include arguments about whether song lyrics constitute literature, but rather about whether Dylan's song lyrics possessed sufficient merit to justify his selection.  Furthermore, song lyrics typically employ poetic elements such as rhyme and meter.  Are Shakespeare's songs not poetry?  If they are, why aren't Cole Porter's, John Lennon's, or Olivia Rodrigo's?